# When is the right time to create Indexes in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-performance

A brand new application with Oracle as DataStore is going to be pushed in Production. The Databases use **CBO** and I have indentified some columns to do indexing. I am expecting the total number of records in a particular table to be 4 million after 6 months. After that very few records will be added and there will not be any updates in the records of Indexed columns. I mean most of the updates will be on NonIndexed columns.

Is it advisable to create Index now? or I need to wait for a couple of months?

Comment: don't see any reason to delay index creation

Comment: Which exact Oracle version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table requires indexes, you will incur a lot of poor performance (full table scan + actual I/O) after the number of rows in the table goes beyond what might reasonably be kept the cache.  Assume that is 20000 rows. We'll call it  magic number. You hit 20000 rows in a week of production. After that the queries and updates on the table will grow progressively slower, on average, as more rows are added.

You are probably worried about the overhead of inserting new rows with indexed fields.  That is a one-time hit. You a trading that against dozens of queries and updates when you delay adding indexes.

The trade off is largely in favor of adding indexes right now.  Especially since we do not know what that magic number (20000?) really is.  Could be larger. Or smaller.